# Is there any API for Google Data Studio to pass Parameters?

Tags: looker-studio, google-developers-console

I am using Google Data Studio for visualization and I want to add my Google Data Studio Reports in my web page. I have a multi page report in Google Data Studio.
I am able to embed and use the link. I want to make the pages as tabs in my web page.
I have 3 report level filter also which work for all the pages in Google Data Studio, but in the web page, if I select the filter in the first tab (first page of Google Data Studio) and I go to the next tab it is not working.

Can I pass the filter values as parameter with URL so that it will also work for another tab?

Apart from embed the URL is there any other option to add the Google Data Studio reports to web page?

Can I pass filter parameter with URL?

Comment: Google Data Studio is having no such feature in the current version. I would like to request the developers to add these features. I have seen these features in tableau and it is very interacting and useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass connector parameters for BigQuery connector and Community Connectors via URL. Here's [more info on Direct links](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/direct-links).

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible in GDS. As every new tab has its own session.

Answer (score -2):

the easiest way is to create a **Text box** named *Page 2*. Then on the **Text Properties**, select *insert link*, and from there **select** *page 2*.

Comment: But this will not help to get the filter work over the different tabs of my web page.