# Does Google Data Studio have API functionality, and if not, will it in the near future?

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, data-visualization, visualization, looker-studio

I'm trying to automate a workflow using **Google Data Studio**. Requirements are simple - I need to be able to programatically copy a templated report (from a Python/Java application) and import/set a data source (Google Sheets doc) for that report. Nothing more fancy (no visualisation creation, formatting, or anything graphical, etc.).

Sources [here](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/api#next_steps), [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/datastudio.googleapis.com?q=datastudio&id=54d3d4f9-3f59-4007-accd-a4d93912fa71&project=wise-analyst-291313) and [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/datastudio.googleapis.com/overview?project=wise-analyst-291313) (last two require Google Cloud Console account) suggest an API does exist (and detail a setup process to access it). However, after going through this setup process, I can find no details or documentation of any functionality, and consequently have been unable to progress.

**Can anyone authoritatively state whether:**

**1. There does exist any API functionality for GDS?** and

**2. If not, are there plans to develop such? (since the Google links above suggest there is, I'm wondering if this means it's in the pipeline for near future).**

The only directly related SO posts I can find are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61612562/is-there-any-rest-api-available-in-data-studio-to-create-a-report-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61093894/is-there-any-api-for-google-data-studio). The first suggests there isn't, but doesn't account for the Google links I've provided above which suggest there is; the second doesn't really cover the same use case, so doesn't provide answers applicable here.

FYI - I've posted a Google Community forum post [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/74561311?hl=en) asking essentially the same question.

If anyone is able to help out, that would be greatly appreciated :) **Many thanks in advance for your time and help! :)**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Fresh as of 2022-05-23*

1. *There does exist any API functionality for GDS?*

   - Not in the way you are expecting. The three links you posted all refer to the current [Data Studio API](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/api). The only things you can do with that API is view your Data Studio assets and update permissions. That's it. This API won't let you create/copy/modify reports or data sources.
2. *If not, are there plans to develop such?*

   - Not in the near future. You can make/vote for this feature request in the [official tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/5278159). More popular feature requests are usually prioritized in roadmaps.

That being said, a lot of the API use cases can be resolved using combinations of [Community Connectors](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector), [config parameters](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-source-parameters), [direct linking](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/direct-links), [viewer's credentials](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/row-level-filtering), [Linking/Integration API](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/share/linking-api) etc.

Comment: Are programmatic interfaces available for managing the assets & permissions? If yes then could you please show me the path forward.

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/api/reference) is all that is available right now.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @MinhazKazi. I have a use case where I am hoping to do exactly what this question describes. My goal is to programmatically create a data studio report from a template and add a data source (google sheet) to that new report (all from python). Can you please confirm this is still not possible? Also, from reading the links you provide, it seems this use is also outside the scope of what community connectors, config parameters, direct linking and viewer credentials can do, does this sound correct to you? Thanks again for the helpful answer you provided!

Comment: You still can't programmatically create a new report from a template. But the new Linking/Integration API might be helpful here. It lets you dynamically define a data source for a report. See details here: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/share/linking-api